# Create Code Signing Certificate on Windows for signing PowerShell scripts

Tags: windows, powershell, openssl, certificate

According to [this guide](http://thecuriousgeek.org/2014/02/creating-openssl-code-signing-certs-on-windows) I tried to create a certificate for signing PowerShell scripts:

```
CD C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin
REM Create the key for the Certificate Authority.  2048 is the bit encryptiong, you can set it whatever you want
openssl genrsa -out C:\Test\ca.key 2048
openssl req -config C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg -new -x509 -days 1826 -key C:\Test\ca.key -out C:\Test\ca.crt
REM Now I'm creating the private key that will be for the actual code signing cert
openssl genrsa -out C:\Test\codesign.key 2048
openssl req -config C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg -new -key C:\Test\codesign.key -reqexts v3_req -out C:\Test\codesign.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 1826 -in C:\Test\codesign.csr -CA C:\Test\ca.crt -CAkey C:\Test\ca.key -extfile C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\cnf\opensslTest.cnf -set_serial 01 -out C:\Test\codesign.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out C:\Test\codesign.pfx -inkey C:\Test\codesign.key -in C:\Test\codesign.crt
```

The following error occurs:

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl x509 -req -days 1826 -in C:\Test\codesign.csr -CA C:\Test\ca.crt -CAkey C:\Test\ca.key -extfile C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\cnf\openssl.cnf -set_serial 01 -out C:\Test\codesign.crt
Error Loading extension section default
14516:error:22097082:X509 V3 routines:do_ext_nconf:unknown extension name:crypto\x509v3\v3_conf.c:78:
14516:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extension:crypto\x509v3\v3_conf.c:47:name=HOME, value=.
```

I used [OpenSSL v1.1.0c](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html). Every other guide I found creates certificates that are not usable for code signing.

Comment: You didn't correctly follow the instructions you linked; it says 'create a **NEW .cfg file** and put the exact same properties as above (**without the [ v3_req ] header**)' (emphasis added) and it then uses **that** file for `-extfile` NOT openssl.cnf. Although part of those instructions, to set extensions in the CSR, are useless; `openssl ca` with unpatched config ignores CSR extensions, and uses _only_ the config plus options for `ca`. That said I agree with @Crypt32 the windows builtin tools are simpler, and a real CA better.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no need in OpenSSL on Windows. On Windows 7, you can use my own PowerShell script I published on TechNet Script Gallery: [Self-signed certificate generator (PowerShell)](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/self-signed-certificate-5920a7c6). The usage can be something like this:

```
New-SelfsignedCertificateEx -Subject "CN=Test Code Signing" `
-EKU "Code Signing" `
-KeySpec "Signature" `
-KeyUsage "DigitalSignature" `
-FriendlyName "Test code signing" `
-NotAfter $([datetime]::now.AddYears(5))
```

(very first example).

Starting with Windows 8, you can use built-in `certreq.exe` tool to generate the certificate. Create INF file with cert configuration, for example:

```
[NewRequest]
Subject = "CN=Test Code Signing"
KeyLength = 2048
KeyAlgorithm = RSA
ProviderName = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider"
MachineKeySet = false
Exportable = true
KeySpec = 2
KeyUsage = 0x80
RequestType = Cert
[EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]
OID=1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 ; Code signing
```

and then run the following command:

```
Certreq –new path\inffilename.inf
```

This will generate and install the certificate to current user's certificate store.

Starting with Windows 10, you can use built-in PowerShell cmdlet as follows:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\currentuser\my `
-Subject "CN=Test Code Signing" `
-KeyAlgorithm RSA `
-KeyLength 2048 `
-Provider "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider" `
-KeyExportPolicy Exportable `
-KeyUsage DigitalSignature `
-Type CodeSigningCert
```

However, self-signed certificate usage for code signing in production environments is discouraged. You should use them in test environments only.

For private usage (within the organization only), you should check if company already owns PKI infrastructure and contact appropriate personnel to receive company-approved code signing certificate.

For public scripts (you are going to distribute along with software packages, or deliver scripts to your customers), I would suggest to purchase code signing from globally trusted commercial CA provider.

Comment: I think you lost a linebreak on the INF file.

Comment: "Globally trusted commercial CA provider" - is difficult to ascertain whether said entity (if you find one) remains in trust for the duration of your cert, and/or if there will be anyone left after to sign one for you.

Comment: Following your "Starting with windows 10..." cmdlet, I got an "unknown error" trying to sign code. Exporting then importing the new cert cleared this up as mentioned here: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4753#issuecomment-341851925

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with openssl. Add a section

```
[ authenticode_cert ]
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
extendedKeyUsage=codeSigning
nsCertType = objsign
```

to openssl.cnf. Create a key and a request as described in the guide linked by OP. There are different methods for signing with openssl. While the guide uses the command `openssl x509` for signing, I prefer:

```
openssl ca -startdate 230101000000Z -enddate 301231225959Z -extensions authenticode_cert -policy policy_any -in codesign.csr -out codesign.crt
```

Finally export as PKCS12 as described and install the resulting `.pfx` as trusted publisher.

IMHO the stuff which the guids says about `[ v3_req ]` can be safely ignored. The above section does the job. It is enough to specify the name of the section when signing.

I even found that adding anything else except `codeSigning` to `extendedKeyUsage` will make the certificate unusable for MS code signing.